# How to detect device information like OS, browser, device name etc. in asp.net web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a ASP.NET Web API.
I want to detect device information of consumer of my web service.
Currently, I am trying to use Request.Headers.UserAgent to get device related information.

```
public void XYZ(int a, int b)
{            
        var x = Request.Headers.UserAgent;
}
```

But unable to get the proper information.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `HttpBrowserCapabilities` class for this in `ASP.NET`. Just get the `Browser` property of the `Request` you receive.

```
HttpBrowserCapabilities capability= Request.Browser;
var BrowserName = capability.Browser;
var version = capability.Version;
var platform = capability.Platform;
```

`HttpBrowserCapabilities` belongs to `System.Web` namespace.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Request.Browser is not available in ASP.NET Web API application. I think you are talking about a ASP.NET Web Application.
I want to detect consumer's device information in my ASP.NET Web API application.

Answer (score 1):

```
Request.Headers["User-Agent"]
```

Provides you the user agent information. Typically the value looks like:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://michaconrad.com/Documentation/Blog/aspnet_5_accessing_environment_variables) you are sir.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IRuntimeEnvironment runtime = PlatformServices.Default.Runtime;
    IApplicationEnvironment env = PlatformServices.Default.Application;
    Console.WriteLine($@"
IApplicationEnvironment:
        Base Path:      {env.ApplicationBasePath}
        App Name:       {env.ApplicationName}
        App Version:    {env.ApplicationVersion}
        Runtime:        {env.RuntimeFramework}
IRuntimeEnvironment:
        OS:             {runtime.OperatingSystem}
        OS Version:     {runtime.OperatingSystemVersion}
        Architecture:   {runtime.RuntimeArchitecture}
        Path:           {runtime.RuntimePath}
        Type:           {runtime.RuntimeType}
        Version:        {runtime.RuntimeVersion}");
}
```

Comment: I need to detect device information (Consumer/Requestor of my Web API) in a ASP.NET Web API not in a Console Application.

Comment: @user1780538 although this _looks_ like a console app, it is in fact how to access the variables in a .Net Core Web API project.